# Classe não localizada

Tags: java, maven

Estou testando um .jar onde vou passar parâmetros nomeados na linha de comando, etc. O problema é que não está encontrando minha classe principal. Alguém me ajuda?

```
package appOptions;

import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Options options = new Options();
        options.addOption("t", true, "Teste");

        CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
        CommandLine cmd = parser.parse( options, args);

        if(cmd.hasOption("t")) {
            System.out.println("Funcionou");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Não funcionou");
        }

    }

}
```

E meu arquivo pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.roknauta</groupId>
    <artifactId>appOptions</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.roknauta.addOption.src.main.java.addOptions.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Já mudei caminho e nada.

Comment: Tente o plugin maven-assembly-plugin segue a documentação. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-assemblies.html

Comment: Adicione a sua classe completa, incluindo o nome do package e os imports.

Comment: Pronto @FelipeMarinho

Answer (score 0):

Mude isso:

```
<mainClass>com.roknauta.addOption.src.main.java.addOptions.Main</mainClass>
```

Para:

```
<mainClass>appOptions.Main</mainClass>
```

Comment: Não foi :( . `Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal addOption.Main`

Comment: @Douglas Você colocou no seu pom.xml `<mainClass>appOptions.Main</mainClass>` ou `<mainClass>addOptions.Main</mainClass>´? Além disso, como você está criando/executando o jar?

Comment: Testei das 2 maneiras. Estou criando com o `mvn package` e executando com o `java -jar <arquivo>`

Comment: @Douglas Ao invés de usar `mvn package`, tente usar `mvn clean package`.